# euler's theorem of homogeneuos function

Tags: calculus

suppose that $f$ is a mapping from $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.

a positively homogeneous of degree $n$ and suppose $f_1, f_2, .... f_N$ are continuous for $a \neq 0$. then 
 $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_if_i(a)= n*f(a)$$

now, they asked me to prove this. (Which is a total no no to me)

I write my proof as;

$f$ is a mapping from $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$  A homogeneous function of degree $n$ if for all $a \in \mathbb R^n$ and all $L>0$, $f(La)=L^n\,f(a)$.
let $a \in \mathbb R^n$ and define function $g$ be a mapping from $[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$. so I write $g(L) = f(La)-L^nf(a)$. then $L≥0$ let $L=0$ then, $g(L)=0$ and therefore $g'(x) =0$?

then i don't know what's goes next. can anyone help me about this?

Comment: Use `$ ... $` around equations (e.g. `$ 2^n $` = $2^n$) to get proper formatting. See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more info.

Comment: Note:  I tried to reformat your question, but I couldn't really follow it.  I might, therefore, have accidentally introduced some errors.  Please check it over.

Comment: thank a lot for this. sorry for that anyway. i'm really bad in writting

Answer (score 1):

By assumption we have
$$f(\lambda x)=\lambda^n f(x)\qquad\forall\lambda>0,\quad  \forall\>x\ne0\ .$$
We now take the partial derivative with respect to $\lambda$ on both sides. On the LHS we have to use the chain rule, and obtain
$$\sum_{i=1}^nf_{.i}(\lambda x)\>x_i=n\lambda^{n-1} f(x)\ .$$
Euler's formula results if you put $\lambda:=1$ here:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\>f_{.i}(x)=n\>f(x)\qquad\forall\>x\ne0\ .$$
You can write this in the following condensed form:
$$x\cdot\nabla f(x)=n\>f(x)\qquad\forall\>x\ne0\ .$$

Comment: But they asking me how to prove this this?

Comment: The above is a proof.

Comment: Got it! Thank yo for the help.